# Changing data source of an existing Power BI report preserving visuals

Tags: powerbi

I have an existing Power BI report (.pbix file). Its data source is an Access (.mdb file) (I don't have the .mdb file).

I'd like to change the data source to MSSQL database. The tables and fieds will be the same most of the time,
with a few differencies.

How can I do it minimizing the workload and preserving all visuals, data model etc.?

When I want to change the data source via `File -> Options and settings -> Data source settings` the `Change Source` button
is grayed out (disabled).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new import query using your MSSQL source
2. Apply all necessary steps so that it resembles your Excel import table
3. Open that query in the Advanced editor and copy all lines
4. Open your Excel import table in the Advanced editor, delete all lines and paste in the lines from step 3
5. Since you don't change your original table name, all visuals will be preserved.